# Resource Maintenance

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a Resource with 10 Units. I want that 1 unit out of them goes for scheduled maintenance. But the Maintenance option under the resource tab is sending all the 10 units for maintenance at the same time. Can I select only 1 at a time? I just want out of 10, only 1 goes under maintenance according to the schedule. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just split the 10 resources into two resource pools, one with a maintenance schedule and one without.

Seize from both pools for all blocks where you were seizing from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your setup for the resource pool. By default the maintenance is created for each unit in the resource pool individually, depending on your settings they should not all go for maintenance at the same time.

See simple example below. I changed the default maintenance settings slightly to get a better example.

[image]

And never get a situation where all 10 goes for maintenance at the same time. See below, the time plot is simply plotting `resourcePool.idle()`

[image]

If however you used deterministic values instead of distributions in your maintenance setup you will find that they all go off and on maintenance at exactly the same time.

[image]

[image]